# Is it possible to get make left padding like this, without changing HTML?

Tags: css, xhtml

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/372594/110528103234-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/372594/110528103234-My-Desktop.png)

How to achieve this with this code.

```
<a href="#">Click to Donate to save rabits</a>

a {background:url(rabit.gif); padding-left:70px}
```

I'm getting like this.

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/372599/110528103631-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/372599/110528103631-My-Desktop.png)

I know it's possible if with change in HTML , but is it possible to achieve this with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
a {
    background:url(rabit.gif) no-repeat; 
    padding-left:70px; 
    width:50px; 
    font:bold 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    float:left;
    height:194px;
}
```

html

```
<a href="#">Click to Donate to save rabits</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<a href="#"><img src="rabit.gif" />Click to Donate to save Rabits</a>
```

and then:

```
img {float: left}
```

Comment: I want to use image in background of `a`